# Spring boot without web but with actuator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Is it possible to run Spring Boot Application without web part but with actuator?
For instance I'd like to process some background operations.

My Application properties

```
management.server.port=8081
server.shutdown=graceful
spring.lifecycle.timeout-per-shutdown-phase=20s
```

Dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When I run the app it stops and not running in background. Did not found the answer in the documentation.

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: Adding the dependency `runtimeOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")` (Gradle) will work, if you cannot find a solution to have the HTTP actuator without adding a Web server dependency.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible or at least it will run without any errors but stop right after it get startet. Spring Boot starter web actually run an embedded server (Tomcat, Jetty, Netty ...) wich keep the process up.